# DVD Creating / Burning Tools for Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dvd, burning, video-editor

I am a serious collector of professional boxing videos and prefer watching them on old-fashioned tv/dvd player set instead of any computer set-up.

Previously as a Windows user I have done 100's of custom-made dvd's with music track, custom menus etc. on Cyberlink PowerDirector -products (I do have PD15 on my laptop, but can't seemingly run it thru' Wine).

I have also burned 100's of those dvd's - previously with Nero-products and later with Ashampoo Burning Studio 16 (again - doesn't seem to work thru' Wine).

Now - which would be the best substitute programmes for Linux? Not a problem if they are "paid products" as long as they work in professional-level.

Brasero sure doesn't work with dvd's created for stand-alone dvd-player. It seems not to understand .ifo / .vob / .bup -files at all... All my dvd's are based on that structure...

Comment: As far as burning you can use ImgBurn in wine (set to win 7), it's as good & probably superior to those you mentioned.. For authoring a bit sparse, DVDStyler & 'Q' DVD-Author are ok.

Comment: Thanks for a hint about ImgBurn. Seems like that could be an answer for half of a problem. 

DVDStyler & "Q" both seem rather odious though... Do not appear to be satisfactory at all. 

Too bad, but thanks.

Comment: Did you tried [k3b](https://userbase.kde.org/K3b)? Or maybe [DeVeDe](https://devede.org/operation)? They are available in repositories.

Comment: Why is DVD styler odius ? I have had good results with it in the past. These days I just find it far easier to encode to h264 and play directly from a stream or removable media.

Comment: None of the programmes you propose seem to combine video editing (clipping, frame-by-frame analysing) and dvd creation functions. Actually, forgot to say but while I haven't done it for a little while - I also use PowerDirector for digitizing VHS tapes. Still have a treasury trove of some 300 tapes (1000 hours) of "lost" boxing history.

Comment: See here for video editors, otherwise stick to windows for something you already know, https://opensource.com/article/18/4/new-state-video-editing-linux

Comment: Great link, Doug!!!! Thank you so much - I've been trying to find that kind of an info package but failed to search that one. It didn't answer all the questions (no mention about possible ability of digitizing VHS...), but gave a lot of insight and I will approach the writer for additional questions!